# MVC One controller many Index view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I've searched many topics but I couldn't find answer for my question. I'm using MVC 6.

I have following structure:

```
> Controllers
  > AccountController
> Views
  > Account
      Index.cshtml
    > MyReviews
        Index.cshtml
```

The AccountController looks like:

```
//
// GET: /Account/Index
[AllowAnonymous] //temp
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
//
// GET: /Account/MyReviews/Index
[AllowAnonymous] //temp
[HttpGet]
[Route("/Account/MyReviews/")]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

If it has different name and is placed in separate controller its working fine:

```
public class MyReviewsController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Account/MyReviews/Default
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/Account/MyReviews/")]
    public IActionResult Default()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I want to have MyReviews working on using only AccountController:

```
http://my.domain/Account/MyReviews/
```

Comment: Sorry, what's the problem?

Comment: I want to have it working from one controller.

Comment: Just add two attributes?

Comment: Will you answer my question or not? Add constructive comment or stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you must enable attribute routing if you want multiple Index actions inside 1 controller. To enable this add  the following to the `RouteConfig.cs`

```
 routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

After this rename the `MyReviews\Index.cshtml` to `MyReviewsIndex.cshtml` inside the `Account` folder (Delete the MyReviews folder). So it looks like the following

```
> Controllers
  > AccountController
> Views
  > Account
      Index.cshtml
      MyReviewsIndex.cshtml

//
// GET: /Account/Index
[AllowAnonymous] //temp
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
//
// GET: /Account/MyReviews/Index
[AllowAnonymous] //temp
[HttpGet]
[Route("Account/MyReviews")]
public IActionResult MyReviewsIndex()
{
    return View();
}
```

Now you can acces the 2 actions by:

```
http://localhost/account 
http://localhost/account/myreviews
```